# sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping import csv to table issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping, sqlbulkcopy

I am at a loss. I am trying to import columns from a csv into an existing data table. I believe the best way to do this is through column mapping using sqlbulkcopy but i just cant wrap my head around this. Im using the script below with the out-datatable function to do column mapping and even though it appears to insert the data, when i run a query i cannot find it. What am i doing wrong?

```
 import-module .\functions.psm1

# Database variables 
$sqlserver = "Db-test-dev\sql2008" 
$database = "Employees" 
#$table = "dbo.tblPersonal" 
$csvfile = "C:\temp\cidb_test.csv" 

 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.connectionstring = "Data Source=$sqlserver;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$database;" 

$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv ‘$csvfile’ | Out-DataTable

$sqlBulkCopy = New-Object (“Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy”) -ArgumentList $SqlConnection
$sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = “dbo.tblpersonal”

$ColumnMap1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(1, 1)
$ColumnMap2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(2, 2)
#$ColumnMap3 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(2, 3)
$sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap1)
$sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap2)
#$sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap3)

$SqlConnection.Open()
$sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer($CSVDataTable)
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: I revamped the entire script and was able to add column mapping. The datatable is built in memory and then mapped to the columns in the sql table. Everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Added column mapping using bulkcopy

```
$ColumnMap1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('SSN','SSN')
$ColumnMap2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('LastName', 'LastName')
$ColumnMap3 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('MiddleName','MiddleName')
$ColumnMap4 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('FirstName','FirstName')
$ColumnMap5 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('PreferredName','PreferredName')
$ColumnMap6 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('WorkPhone','WorkPhone')
$ColumnMap7 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('Email','Email')
$ColumnMap8 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('EmpType','EmpType')
$ColumnMap9 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('HireDate', 'HireDate')
$ColumnMap10 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('ACID','ACID')
$ColumnMap11 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('OPID','OPID')
$ColumnMap12 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('Floor','Floor')
$ColumnMap13 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('Department','Department')
$ColumnMap14 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping('Division','Division')
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap1)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap2)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap3)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap4)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap5)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap6)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap7)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap8)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap9)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap10)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap11)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap12)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap13)
$BulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($ColumnMap14)
```